# android why swipe on a textview will trigger onclick event?

Tags: android, onclick, swipe

I am using the default project template from Android Studio. When I swipe on the textView, the `onClick` event will get triggered. Is it the designed behavior or where did I do something wrong?

[image: the codes]

Comment: How exactly gets clicked ? You have any listener set on the text ?

Comment: yes, I set up a onclick listener on the textview. If I move finger from left to right or right to left, the onclick event will get trigger just the same way as it will get trigger with a single tap.

Comment: I think this is how it should happen. If you really want to `fix` this behavior you should take a look at `TouchListener` and `do same stuff as onClick` but inside `ACTION_DOWN`. Anyway, unless you are going to have more complex actions there, I don't think this bothers a lot :)

Comment: I would say that this is quite normal, but depends of your implementation. Show some code. If you have some mechanism to consume click in the case of swipe, as for example `ViewPager` than click will not be called on that TextView.

Comment: @lonut, thanks for your suggestion. But I want to figure out if it is the default behavior of a textview or if it is only my problem? Will this happen on your Android Studio?

Comment: to understand the problem, you have to think about *what a click event is*. So it is: finger down + finger up. So basically the swipe is the same finger down + **finger move** + finger up. This means that each swipe is a click.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.txt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("textview", "clicked");
            }
        });
    }

Comment: @Vladyslav, so it is the default behavior that both swipe and single tap will trigger the View.OnClickListener event?

Comment: yes. I do detect swipes manually with onTouch listener by checking the diff between finger down x/y and finger up x/y, but probably there are better ways.

Comment: using onTouch to detect click and swipe is really troublesome and complex.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `OnClick` is triggered because when you put your finger on `textView` its `ACTION_DOWN` method gets called internally and after swipe when you remove your finger its `ACTION_UP` method gets called internally. So whenever these two combination gets called it calls the `onClick` method. So when you touch (`ACTION_DOWN`) the `textView` and swipe left/right and move your finger outside (without the `ACTION_UP` event) it won't get called because its `ACTION_UP` is not called.

PS. This is not the official definition/working of `onClick`... This is how it worked in my experience.

Comment: the bigger problem is that I cannot implement the swipe gesture on the parent ViewGroup  while implement onClicklistener on the textview correctly.

Comment: I think this is a separate question... This is just the working of `onClick`... you can always implement `onTouch` of textView. There are plenty of answer to your problem (what you mentioned in comments).

Comment: @StoneLai check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745344/detecting-swipe-and-tap-gestures) out..

Answer (score 0):

my solution is extending the parent viewgroup and examining motionevent in the onInterceptTouchEvent.